# How to pull from remote to local branch

Tags: git

So I create a local branch from master.

Since then the origin has changed.

How can I pull from the origin to the local branch.

So I have the following branches:

```
master
f1.1
```

How can I pull from the remote origin to f1.1 to keep it updated?

Comment: please add the output of `git branch -vv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on `f1.1`, and you want to pull from the origin master branch, you'd do:

`git pull --rebase origin master`

If the `f1.1` branch on origin has changed, it'd be:

`git pull --rebase origin f1.1`

Comment: no the f1.1 is local branch. how do I pull from the origin to my local branch?

Comment: You don't pull, you have to push first to create it on the remote repo. Edit: That is if its not there

Comment: Right.  You're on `f1.1` locally.  So it depends on what you want to pull from origin, either `master` or `f1.1` as shown above.

Comment: As stated by @john-rummel, if you don't have `f1.1` on origin, you'll need to push it there first as well.